Proving that a curve is $C^\infty$

Let $\alpha : [0, + \infty) \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be a map defined as $\alpha(0) = (0,0)$ and $\forall t > 0 : \alpha (t) = (e^{-1/t} \cos (1/t) , e^{-1/t} \sin (1/t)) $ . Prove that $\alpha$ is $C^\infty$ on all $[0, +\infty) $ .

I am posting this excercise from my Differential geometry book since I think that it is very easy but I am very stuck and I do not see it clearly.
My problem is that, since obviously $\alpha$ is $C^\infty$ on all $(0, +\infty) $ because on that interval it is a composition and product of $C^\infty$ maps, I have tried to search a pattern on $\alpha^{(k)}$ (the $k$ derivative of $\alpha$) in order to justify its continuity on $0$ by applying the definition of derivative on a specific point (I mean $\alpha^{(k+1)} (0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\alpha^{(k)}(h) - \alpha^{(k)}(0)}{h}$ ) , but I do not see any pattern related to $k$ when I start to derivate, so any possible help or advice would be very appreciated.

I think the key is that the exponential map will force any of your derivates to decrease "faster" to 0 than h. Also by induction assumption your k-th derivate should be 0 at 0.

Consider the function $g(t) = e^{-1/t}$ for $t\neq0 (t\in\mathbb{R})$. Then it is well-known that:
$$
g^{(n)}(t) =
P_n\big(\frac{1}{t} \big)\, e^{- 1/t}
$$
where $ P_n $ is an $ n $-th order polynomial with $ P_0 = 1 $, satisfying the recursive relation:
$$
P_n(x) = x^2 \left( P^{'}_{n-1} (x) - P_{n-1}(x) \right)
$$
This equation can be derived algebraically.
Now, consider the function $h(z)=e^{-({1-i})/{z}} = e^{-1/z}(\cos{\frac{1}{z}} + i \sin{\frac{1}{z}} )$ on the open complex region $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ defined as:
$$
A := \left\{\,r e^{i \theta}: r>0, \theta\in \big(-\frac{7}{12}\pi, \, \frac{1}{12}\pi \big) \right\}\,.
$$
Region $A$ on complex plain $\mathbb{C}$ looks like:
$\hspace{5cm}$
Note also that region $A$ contains positive real line $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
It is clear that $h: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and algebraically
$$
h^{(n)}(z) = \frac{1}{(1-i)^n} P_n\big(\frac{1-i}{z}\big)\, e^{-({1-i})/{z}}
$$
for $z \in A$.
Now, we would show $\underline{\forall z\in A:\lim_{z \to 0 , z\in A} \frac{1}{z} h^{(n)}(z) = }\:0 \:\: (\bigstar)$.
Let write $z = |z|\,e^{i (\theta \,-\, \pi/4)}$, where $\theta \in (-\pi/3\,, \pi/3)$. Since $\cos(\theta) > 1/2$:
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{1-i}{z}\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{2^{1/2}}{|z|}e^{-i\theta} \right) = \exp\left( -\frac{2^{1/2}}{|z|} \cos(\theta) \right) \cdot \exp \left(i \,\frac{2^{1/2}}{|z|} sin(\theta) \right) \\ \Longrightarrow \left| \exp\left(-\frac{1-i}{z}\right) \right| \leq \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2^{1/2}|z|} \right)\,, 
$$
we have:
$$
\left| h^{(n)}(z) \right| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\, \tilde{P}_n \left( \frac{2^{1/2}}{|z|} \right) \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2^{1/2}|z|} \right)\,,
$$
where $\tilde{P}_n$ is a polynomial that coefficients are absolute values of $P_n$'s. Because $\lim_{t\to \infty}(Q(t) /e^t ) = 0$ for any polynomial, we can conclude that $(\bigstar)$ holds.
Now, let $h|_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}(x) = u(x) + i\, v(x)$ where $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ take real values. Clearly $h|_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}^{(n)}(x) = u^{(n)}(x) + i\, v^{(n)}(x) $ and $h|_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}^{(n)}(x) = h^{(n)}|_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}(x)$ since $h$ is analytic.
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x} u^{(n)}(x) = \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x}v^{(n)}(x) = 0.
$$
Now consider that $u(x) = e^{-1/x} \cos(1/x)$ and $v(x) = e^{-1/x} \sin(1/x)$, from above equation we can derive that $^{(n)}(0) := \lim_{t \to 0+} \big( \frac{1}{t} (^{(n-1)}(t) - ^{(n-1)}(0)) \big)$ is zero for all $n$ by induction.

It is very dangerous here to consider the functions in the complex plane...

@Jochen Can you point out the point that can make an error?

Are you sure exponentials grow faster than polynomials in $\Bbb C$? Hint: Consider $e^z$ and $P(z)$ on the imaginary axis. This is the key point, of course, to the original question in $\Bbb R$.

@Ted Shifrin (and Mr.Jochen) Oh.. Thank you for the pointing out. It was so basic. And I feel that I can fix my solution so please check from next few hours. Thank you again masters for waiting and teaching.., in respect.

I re-updated my solution. Please check!!
